# Determine the element that failed an XSD schema validation in python

Tags: python, xsd, lxml

I'm currently using lxml to parse and validate xml against an XSD schema with python. Now I would like to get the element that causes the validation to fail. The raised exception gives text only information about the error:

```
Element 'intval': [facet 'maxInclusive'] The value '
          150000
      ' is greater than the maximum value allowed ('30')., line 12
```

Any Idea how to properly get the element that caused the error? A solutions that would not involve parsing the text would be most welcome.